# Footer in a RelativeLayout with a android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, footer

I have a small problem, normally this code to put a footer in a RelativeLayout using android: layout_above has worked for me, but now I need to use a LinearLayout, android:layout_above does not work, as you can see in the photo
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wtSy.jpg)

If instead of a LinearLayout you use a RelativeLayout, the Footer OK, the ToolBar KO, as you can see in the photo 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGyM0.jpg)

The layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSettings"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/statusBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/statusBarHeight"
    android:background="?colorPrimaryDark"
    android:translationZ="4dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:translationZ="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/footer"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Li1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Li2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/2" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Li3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/3" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Li4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/4" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Li5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/5" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The footer:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/footer"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will solve your problem if you want the footer to be below your contentLayout
try changing your footer to this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/footer"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then change the `contentLayout` **@+id/...** to **@id/...**

Comment: With android:layout_below="@+id/contentLayout" the Footer disappears

Comment: i think this is because your RelativeLayout height is match parent and so it would take all the height

Comment: i suggest you put all of your RelativeLayout which has the id="@+id/scrollView" with all of its childs inside a scroll view and see if that helps